# Mobile Connect - Add a second mobile number to a contact

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect, sms

We sent an SMS to a contact using the same API call

```
"POST /messageContact/{id}/send"

{   "Subscribers": [{ "MobileNumber": "39334320430",
    "SubscriberKey": "11111"  }],
    "Subscribe": true,
    "Resubscribe": false,
    "keyword": "OK",
    "Override": true,
    "messageText": "Reply OK to +39333456576"
}
```

Then we changed the first mobile number with a second one related to this contact into a Data Extension.

We tried to send a second SMS with the same API parameters (obviously with a different MobileNumber). But we noticed that, despite the result of the call is accepted (code 202), in the Membership page inside Mobile connect, the system didn't add a new subscription and i didn't receive any SMS.

Is it a standard behavior in mobile connect feature? Do you have any advice?

Answer (score 1):

I've acomplished this by inactivating the first contact and addin one to its priority attribute:

```
"PATCH https://www.exacttargetapis.com/contacts/v1/contacts"
{
"contactKey": "<YOUR CONTACT KEY>",
"attributeSets": [
{
    "name": "MobileConnect Demographics",
    "items": [{
        "values": [
        {
            "name": "Mobile Number",
            "value": "<YOUR MOBILE>"
        },
        {
            "name": "status",
            "value": "2"
        },
        {
            "key": "CreatedDate",
            "value": "2016-11-11"
        },
        {
            "key": "ModifiedDate",
            "value": "2016-11-11"
        },
         {
            "key": "Priority",
            "value": "2"
        }]
    }]
}]
}
```

Then you can try to send an SMS to the 2nd mobile number.

Comment: Hi @SebOB, i followed your suggestion. The Status of the first mobile number is changed (Now it is set to "Inactive"); however the Priority is still set to "1". I tried to send me an SMS, but I didn’t received it.
Then I tried to add also this code in the API call {"values": [{ "name": "Mobile Number","value": "393334549659"}, {"key": Priority", "value": "1"}, {"name": "status", "value": "1"} in order to change the priority related to the 2nd mobile number, but it doesn’t work.

Comment: Hi, please ensure you have 2 mobiles under the same subscriberKey one Active and the other Inactive. And that  you are trying to send the SMS to the active one. Also try to set the Locale attribute to 'IT' (according to the prefix39) to the active contact

Comment: I confirm you that now in MobileConnect Demographics section I can see two mobile numbers (the first one on Inactive status with Priority equals to 1 and locale ‘it’; the second one on Active status with Priority equals to 2 and locale ‘IT’). Then I sent an SMS to the second mobile number, but I didn’t received it.

Comment: The only thing I can think about is that another contact has the second mobile number active.

Comment: What i have noticed is that i cannot subscribe the second mobile number to the keyword (or another different one). If i also try to add manually th subscription, the system gives back this error "An error occurred attempting to save the mobile subscription. Contact Global Support for additional assistance regarding this error." Probably this is the reason why the call has failed.